# Render/retrieve data from firebase database in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[the screenshot of the realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeFgu.jpg)I created `name` and `age` in the database already using the `set` function. I want to render and retrieve data from firebase real time database in react native instead of Here word in the components. How do I achieve that?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,Image,Button,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
//import  firebase from '@firebase/app';
//import '@firebase/auth';
//import '@firebase/database';
import firebase from 'firebase';    

 export default class App extends Component{  
 componentWillMount(){  
  var config = {
      apiKey: "**********",
      authDomain: "**********.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://********.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "*******",
      storageBucket: "********.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "*********"
    };
firebase.initializeApp(config);    
firebase.database().ref('users/001').set(  
{  
name:'noor adam',
age:45  
 }).then(()=>{console.log('inserted');}).catch((error)=> . 
 {console.log('error');}); 
}  
render(){ 
return(  
<View><Text>Here</Text></View>
   )  
 }  
}
```

Instead of the Here word in the render, i want to retrieve the name and the age from the firebase database.

Comment: Are you getting a snapshot via something like:
 ` database.ref('users/' + uid).on('value', (snapshot) =>{})`?  What does the data look like?

Comment: do you the structure of the data as screen shot?

Comment: Sure, although a snippet of actual data might be more useful.

Comment: i added it (the screenShot)

Comment: Okay so next you want to get that data back into your app?                                                  
`database.ref('users/' + uid).on('value', (snapshot) =>{ 
console.log(snapshot.val())
}) `  To see if the snapshot logs to the console

Comment: yes it appear in the console, i want the data in the app interface

Comment: For now why don't you add a new lifecycle method - `ComponentDidMount() {
database.ref('users/' + uid).on('value', (snapshot) =>{ console.log(snapshot.val()) })
}`

Comment: Can you show me what it looks like in the console?  I'm going to put my next response in a snippet/answer.

Comment: can you add it now if you can?

Comment: It's there now..

Comment: thank you alot for the help and respone but now i face error that said                                  bundling failed: SyntaxError: C:\Users\asus\ruqApp\node_modules\react-native\scripts\App.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (24:20)

  22 |  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  23 |
> 24 | componentDidMount() {
     |                     ^
  25 | firebase.database().ref('users/001').on('value', (snapshot) =>{
  26 |    this.setState({
  27 |       name: snapshot.val().name,

Comment: I made another change but like I said, it's fairly pseudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the real-time data value with `snapshot`. This example places the snapshot in `componentDidMount`, which is called after `componentWillMount`.

This is a bit pseudo, but since you're using React class, I've added a constructor.  It makes the use of `this` predictable.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, 
View,Image,Button,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
//import  firebase from '@firebase/app';
//import '@firebase/auth';
//import '@firebase/database';
import firebase from 'firebase';    

 export default class App extends Component{  
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
}
  componentWillMount(){  
  var config = {
  apiKey: "**********",
  authDomain: "**********.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://********.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "*******",
  storageBucket: "********.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "*********"
};
 firebase.initializeApp(config);    
 firebase.database().ref('users/001').set(  
  {  
  name:'noor adam',
  age:45  
 }).then(()=>{console.log('inserted');}).catch((error)=> . 
 {console.log('error')})
 .then(() => {
   firebase.database().ref('users/001').on('value', (snapshot) =>{
   this.setState({
  name: snapshot.val().name,
  age: snapshot.val().age
 })
})
}) 
}  
render(){ 
return(  
<View><Text>Here</Text></View>
 )  
 }  
}
```